# Column Layout Issue in Firefox/IE but not Chrome

Tags: html, css

This is my first question here. I appreciate any and all help.

I recently redesigned my personal website colincronin.com. On the "Photography" section (third nav item) I am using column layout to display a gallery. In Google Chrome everything looks fine. However, in Firefox/IE the fourth row is being forced over so that only two images appear in this row and the third image appears in the next row. This creates blank white spaces where it looks like the photos are missing.

I've included the CSS and HTML I am using. I wanted to include screenshots but I cannot add them directly in the body of the image yet so here are the URLs to the screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfdZl.jpg (Chrome 40.0.2214.115) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WenDq.jpg (Firefox 35.0.1 / IE 10 and 11)

These pics are from a PC, though on Mac Chrome and Firefox render the pages in the same way. Thank you in advance.

Best,
Colin

**CSS:**

```
.one-full,
.one_half,
.one_third,
.two_third,
.one_quarter,
.one_fifth,
.three_quarter,
.two_fifth,
.three_fifth,
.four_fifth
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 .3em .1em 0em;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one_full
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.one_half
{
    width: 50%;
}
.one_third
{
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.two_third
{
    width: 66.66666%;
}
.one_quarter
{
    width: 25%;
}
.one_fifth
{
    width: 20%;
}
.three_quarter
{
    width: 75%;
}
.two_fifth
{
    width: 40%;
}
.three_fifth
{
    width: 60%;
}
.four_fifth
{
    width: 80%;
}

.one_full img,
.one_half img,
.one_third img,
.two_third img,
.one_quarter img,
.one_fifth img,
.three_quarter img,
.two_fifth img,
.three_fifth img,
.four_fifth img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/taroko-gorge.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/taroko-gorge.jpg" alt="Taroko Gorge"></a>
                                </div>                                          
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/giverny-lily-pond.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/giverny-lily-pond.jpg" alt="Giverny Lily Pond"></a>      
                                </div>
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/giza-pyramid.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/giza-pyramid.jpg" alt="Giza Pyramid"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/milwaukee-art-museum.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/milwaukee-art-museum.jpg" alt="Milwaukee Art Museum"></a>
                                </div>                                          
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-01.jpg" alt="Navy Pier 4th of July Fireworks 01"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/dessert-is-served.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/dessert-is-served.jpg" alt="Dessert is Served!"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/seeing-blind.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/seeing-blind.jpg" alt="Seeing Blind"></a>
                                </div>                                          
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/ghosts-in-mirror.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/ghosts-in-mirror.jpg" alt="Ghosts in the Mirror"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="one_third">
                                    <a href="images/photography/chicago-on-the-streets.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="images/photography/chicago-on-the-streets.jpg" alt="On the Streets of Chicago"></a>
                                </div>
```

Comment: what version of firefox? have you checked `border-box` support on the version you are using?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using the most updated version of all the browsers. I added the version numbers into the post above. Chrome 40.0.2214.115, Firefox 35.0.1, IE 10 and 11.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem on [my end](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/c2m5ha2g/). Tested both FF v35 en Chrome v40

Comment: Thanks Tim. Yeah it's strange. Dippas answer solves it for me but I'm still curious as to why it's happening for me only on certain browsers (and yet not for you). Curiously, I use the same layout markup all over the page and in other sections of the site, yet only in this particular place do I see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using the `clearfix` just add class `.clearfix` on your fourth div `.one_third`

like this:

```
<div class="one_full">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-skyline-night-panoramic.jpg">
      <img alt="Panoramic Chicago Skyline at Night" src="images/photography/chicago-skyline-night-panoramic.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/1959-jaguar-xk150.jpg">
      <img alt="1959 Jaguar XK-150" src="images/photography/1959-jaguar-xk150.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/seattle-skyline.jpg">
      <img alt="Seattle Skyline" src="images/photography/seattle-skyline.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/taroko-gorge.jpg">
      <img alt="Taroko Gorge" src="images/photography/taroko-gorge.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/giverny-lily-pond.jpg">
      <img alt="Giverny Lily Pond" src="images/photography/giverny-lily-pond.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/giza-pyramid.jpg">
      <img alt="Giza Pyramid" src="images/photography/giza-pyramid.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_third clearfix">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/milwaukee-art-museum.jpg">
      <img alt="Milwaukee Art Museum" src="images/photography/milwaukee-art-museum.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-01.jpg">
      <img alt="Navy Pier 4th of July Fireworks 01" src="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-01.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/dessert-is-served.jpg">
      <img alt="Dessert is Served!" src="images/photography/dessert-is-served.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/seeing-blind.jpg">
      <img alt="Seeing Blind" src="images/photography/seeing-blind.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/ghosts-in-mirror.jpg">
      <img alt="Ghosts in the Mirror" src="images/photography/ghosts-in-mirror.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-on-the-streets.jpg">
      <img alt="On the Streets of Chicago" src="images/photography/chicago-on-the-streets.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_fifth">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-bucktown-mansion.jpg">
      <img alt="Mansion in Bucktown, Chicago" src="images/photography/chicago-bucktown-mansion.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_fifth">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/candid-thoughts.jpg">
      <img alt="Candid Thoughts" src="images/photography/candid-thoughts.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_fifth">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-02.jpg">
      <img alt="Navy Pier 4th of July Fireworks 02" src="images/photography/chicago-navy-pier-fireworks-02.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_fifth">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/philosopher-sculpture.jpg">
      <img alt="Sculpture of Philosopher's Head" src="images/photography/philosopher-sculpture.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_fifth">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/hot-chocolate.jpg">
      <img alt="Hot Chocolate from Hot Chocolate!" src="images/photography/hot-chocolate.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/fiery-crown-botanical-gardens.jpg">
      <img alt="A Fiery Botanical Crown" src="images/photography/fiery-crown-botanical-gardens.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/uncommon-ground-classical-revolution.jpg">
      <img alt="Classical Revolution Performance @ Uncommon Ground" src="images/photography/uncommon-ground-classical-revolution.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-gold-coast-farmers-market.jpg">
      <img alt="Crepes at the Gold Coast Farmer's Market" src="images/photography/chicago-gold-coast-farmers-market.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-bucktown-motorcycle-rider.jpg">
      <img alt="Bucktown Motorcycle Rider" src="images/photography/chicago-bucktown-motorcycle-rider.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-gold-coast-fence.jpg">
      <img alt="Gold Coast Fence" src="images/photography/chicago-gold-coast-fence.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chiang-kai-shek-memorial.jpg">
      <img alt="Chiang Kai Shek Memorial" src="images/photography/chiang-kai-shek-memorial.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/couple-on-puget-sound.jpg">
      <img alt="A Couple on Puget Sound" src="images/photography/couple-on-puget-sound.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_third">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/istanbul-blue-mosque.jpg">
      <img alt="Blue Mosque Istanbul" src="images/photography/istanbul-blue-mosque.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/andrews-park-soccer-game.jpg">
      <img alt="Soccer Game @ Andrews Park" src="images/photography/andrews-park-soccer-game.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one_half">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/chicago-skyline-lincoln-park.jpg">
      <img alt="Chicago Skyline from Lincoln Park" src="images/photography/chicago-skyline-lincoln-park.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="one_full">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="images/photography/whiskey-collection-2015-01.jpg">
      <img alt="My Humble Little Whiskey Collection" src="images/photography/whiskey-collection-2015-01.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work. Do you have any idea as to why the issue occurs though (and only on certain browsers)? The entire page is comprised of columned rows and this is the only place it happens. I even have multiple 3 column rows lower on the page, and if I move those rows up to where the problem row is I get the same issue (even though the same code appears fine lower in the page).

Answer (score 0):

You should put your images on `display: block` to achieve the correct padding.
If not, all anchors and images behave like inline elements who's dimensions (width*height) will be calculated upon page rendering. Since you use `box-sizing: border-box` this padding just became an issue.

By setting them on "block", the height will be calculated accordingly and the anchors will nicely wrap around them.

This height issue is typical for this kind of grid systems.
You will also notice height issues if your padding is inconsistent (=> JavaScript "equal height" functionality).
For now this is not the case on your end, since the columns on the right have padding as well.

As to your initial issue, try to play with the padding in pixels inside your toolbar (F12) to see what happens and if they adjust normally.

If your based font-size hasn't been setup properly, your rem values are not based on `font-size: 10px` causing inconsistencies again.

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/c2m5ha2g/)**

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll look into this more closely. However, for me I had previously tried using display: block on the img class and it didn't solve the problem for me, nor did altering the padding on the column CSS. It just seems strange that the issue could happen with the exact same code on one part of the page that appeared fine elsewhere. I appreciate your insights.

Comment: Ok Colin, FYI I've used a similar grid setup as you, without any problems.
If you want to take a look it's at connections[dot].be. The `font-size: 10px` is on my `html` node. The [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) is on every `column`. GL!